# How to get JSP parameter in dynamically? (or create JSP parameter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm new to JSP and ajax but trying both at the same time.

I'm making a dynamic tab that can be added or removed with these steps.

I wannna put parameter from controller in the newly added tab's content area.

---

1.When a 'Load Project' button from the list is clicked, add a new tab.

```js
$('<li role="presentation">'
    +'<a href="#'+tabId+'" aria-controls="'+tabId+'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'
    +$projectName
    +' <span class="closeTab glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>'
    +'<input class="hiddenProjectId" type="text" name="projectId" value="'+ pId +'" style="display: none;">'
    +'</a></li>').insertBefore('#liProjectTabAdd');


$('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="'+ tabId + '">'
                + '<div class="projectContent">'
                + '<ul class="blockList list-unstyled draggableList"></ul>'
                + '<div class="table-hover addBlock">'
                + 'add block <span id="addBlockGlyp" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>'
                + '</div></div>'
                + '</div>').appendTo('.projectTab-content');
```

2.call the controller through ajax(post method)

```js
$.post("loadProjectContent.do",
    {
        projectId: pId
    }
);
```

3.The controller call DAO and get the project's content.
(The contents are correct. I checked it with printing)

```js
Project project = new Project();

project.setProjectId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("projectId")));

dao.doGetProjectContent(project);

request.setAttribute("projectContent", project.getProjectContent());
```

---

**Then now, how to get this projectContent in JSP?**

I've tried adding jsp tag when I append the tab, but it was a raw text.

(like ~~~${ projectContent }~~~)

```js
$('<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="'+ tabId + '">'
    + '<div class="projectContent">'
    + '<ul class="blockList list-unstyled draggableList">'
    + '${ projectContent }'
    + '</ul>'
    + '<div class="table-hover addBlock">'
    + 'add block <span id="addBlockGlyp" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>'
    + '</div></div>'
    + '</div>').appendTo('.projectTab-content');
```

---

Please save this newbie

Answer (score 0):

Write the `projectContent` to the response instead of adding it as a request attribute.

On the client side, parse the response of your AJAX request and add it to the DOM.

Comment: Sorry for asking in detail. You mean response method like response.setHeader()?

Comment: No, write it to the response body. Don't know what the type of your `projectContent` is. If it's not a string, you probably want to serialize it to a string or a JSON object first.